# Running k-means clustering with k = 2 recursively on clusters greater than a certain size

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

Does it make sense to run k-means with k (number of clusters) of 2, and then for every cluster bigger than N, run k-means again with k = 2? We can then keep doing it until we have all clusters of size < N.

Please don't focus on the hyperparameter N, which doesn't have a lot of meaning, but focus on the idea of running k-means multiple times with k = 2.

Could it lead to a better result than running k-means only once with k > 2?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it *could* - but only if your dataset has a very specific type of structure. And there's no reason to expect that specific structure to be a common feature of datasets, so I don't expect this would be a generally useful process.

That doesn't mean that k-means is great by itself; there are many modified versions of the algorithm that have proven to be very useful, including k-means++ (which uses an iterative procedure as well), k-medians, and k-mediods.

You may also be interested in [hierarchical-clustering](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-clustering) approaches, which are both useful and seem similar in spirit to what you are proposing.

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly the idea of **bisecting** k-means.

No, the result is *almost certainly worse* (by SSQ) than that of k-means with the same number of clusters. K-means finds (at least almost) a local optimum. The bisection approach does not, as such optimas are usually not hierarchic (the best k=2 and the best k=3 solution do usually *not* have a center in common, for example on 2d uniform data).

Why do you think it will be better? By what notion of "better"?

Comment: I want to cluster pattern on image. Varibility intra and inter cluster is huge. For my experiment I use a small data set of 3000 images. I do feature extraction with different tools (conv net, autoencodeur, T-SNE...) but it's look like using distance tools is bad for clustering => even the methodology which gives me the best value of silouette score give me poor interpratibility result (I used hierarchical and K mean). My idea of many K mean with k=2 is to extract some informative cluster. I'll probably miss important information, but I expect cluster to give me at least some information

Comment: Even if it's hard to says without looking at the data, do you have any idea of what to do when silouette score isn't a good indicator of clustering quality? Since conv net and autoencodeur are working well, can I says feature extraction is good?

Comment: @akhetos You should probably post those as separate questions. Comments are not the best place to resolve major new questions.

Comment: I don't use autoencoders, because they only work on images and I don't use images. Make sure you don't overfit them.